# « Avoir le compas dans l'oeil » : choix de préposition, référence à Michel-Ange ?

Tags: prépositions, étymologie, locutions, italien

On a [*avoir le compas dans l'oeil*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/compas/17620/locution?q=compas%20dans%20l%27oeil#161126) (1740), locution figée, au figuré, familièrement, pour « estimer, à première vue, une dimension aussi exactement qu'avec un compas. » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compas)) On réfère à [*Ac.4*](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=compas) et aux [*Mémoires*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5269x/f25.image) (1740-1750) du duc de [Saint-Simon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Rouvroy_de_Saint-Simon) et on donne aussi comme exemple :

> Les sculpteurs, les peintres surtout, redoutent l'empire de la
>   géométrie (...) ils rappellent volontiers qu'il faut avoir le
>   **compas** *dans l'œil*, suivant le mot de Michel Ange, sans songer que ce grand homme, avant de s'exprimer ainsi, avait eu longtemps le
>   **compas** dans la main.
>
> [ [*Grammaire des arts du dessin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CQhTAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22suivant%20le%20mot%20de%20Michel%20Ange%2C%20sans%20songer%22&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q=%22suivant%20le%20mot%20de%20Michel%20Ange,%20sans%20songer%22&f=false), C. Blanc (1870) ]

On note qu'on n'a pas dit *avoir un compas pour œil*, *avoir l’œil comme un compas*, *avoir un compas devant l’œil* ou *avoir un œil-compas* ; qu'on dit aussi *vif comme l'éclair* mais sans doute pas qu'on a l'éclair dans les jambes ; qu'on a du *cœur au ventre* comme exemple d'un truc à première vue similaire, mais avec la préposition *à*... Enfin, hormis le sens de la locution, avoir un compas dans l’œil est sans doute contre-indiqué et douloureux.

---

- Pourquoi on a la préposition *dans* dans la locution ?
- De quel sens de [*dans*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dans/21617?q=dans#21494) s'agit-il ici (*à l'intérieur*, etc.) ?
- Qu'est-ce que l’œil a de particulier sémantiquement ou conceptuellement qui puisse
  autoriser qu'un objet « à l'intérieur » réalise un sens d'acuité, le cas échéant ?
- Le *compas dans l’œil* est-il un calque de l'italien (quel mot de Michel Ange) ?

Comment: Je ne vois quelle autre préposition pourrait remplacer « dans ». Ce qui compte pour effectuer la mesure c'est le point de vue de l'objet qui mesure, en l’occurrence l’œil, si l’œil doit être aussi précis qu'un compas il faut bien que le compas soit dans l’œil et pas « à la place de » ce qui empêcherait la suite de l'opération qui passe par la vue :  reporter la mesure sur le dessin.

Comment: L'expression complète de Michel-Ange était d'ailleurs « avoir le compas dans l’œil plutôt que dans la main » (donc parallèle : dans ... dans...) expression que les historiens d'art font remonter à  Diodore de Sicile qui avait dit que les Égyptiens avaient la mesure dans la main tandis que les Grecs l'avaient dans les yeux. Au fil du temps le mot « compas » a pris la place de « mesure» pour exprimer la même idée.

Comment: @Laure -- Vos commentaires feraient une belle réponse :) .

Comment: @cl-r Mais je n'ai pas l'impression de répondre vraiment...

Comment: @Laure ... sauf que c'est la seule réponse possible, 'historiquement parlant' en cohérence avec tous les points de la question.

Comment: Avoir le compas dans l'oeil est une expression similaire (si ce n'est pas dérivée, mais impossible pour moi de le prouver...) de "avoir cela dans le sang/la peau" etc. Si elle induit un sens inné, elle introduit sans doute le fait que la personne est douée au point de ne pas avoir besoin de l'objet.

Comment: @Blue_Elephant Si on peut penser que pour le *vulgum pecus* avoir un compas dans l’œil est quelque chose d'inné qui peut s'apparenter à un don, c'est impensable pour l'artiste qui doit effectuer un long apprentissage pour parvenir à l'expression de son art, le don ne suffit pas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michel-Ange reprenait une expression « [avoir le compas dans l’œil et non dans la main](https://books.google.fr/books?id=btssMRSo6jMC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=michel%20ange%20compas%20oeil%20main&source=bl&ots=-jr3Wruao_&sig=lc2Lb0nxipDYCGwKjQU9V31SyLI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjimuC_9erNAhWHAsAKHfBwAyQQ6AEITzAN#v=onepage&q=michel%20ange%20compas%20oeil%20main&f=false) » que les historiens d'art attribuent à Diodore de Sicile (historien grec, I<sup>er</sup> siècle av. J.-C.) et qui avait dit que les Égyptiens avaient la mesure dans la main tandis que les Grecs l'avaient dans les yeux.<sup>1</sup>

Le parallèle entre la main et l’œil montre clairement que l'instrument de mesure du dessinateur fait partie intégrante de l’œil (il est donc « dans » l’œil »), c'est à dire que c'est la vue qui doit effectuer la mesure et ensuite la reporter sur le papier. Un plasticien pourrait certainement développer ce point qui est, il me semble, important dans la représentation en perspective.

Michel-Ange a opéré le glissement du mot « mesure »  à celui de « compas », qui est l'instrument utilisé par le dessinateur pour effectuer la mesure. La seule autre préposition qui pourrait convenir pour rendre la même idée serait *à*, les deux mots peuvent être parfois quasi synonymes :

> [Le maître de dessin, le maître d'écriture font-ils donc autre chose que de vous mettre une plume ou un crayon à la main ?](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=m2UTAAAAQAAJ&q=crayon%20%C3%A0%20la%20main#v=snippet&q=crayon%20%C3%A0%20la%20main&f=false)

« dans la main » exprimerait ici la même idée.

Et si on veut vraiment jouer sur les mots en traitant l'expression de façon littérale, pour pouvoir effectuer la mesure le compas serait placé poignée vers l'intérieur du corps, l’œil manipulant le compas (comme une main pourrait le faire) et les pointes qui effectuent la mesure orientées vers l’extérieur.

---

<sup>1</sup> [*Histoire de la peinture en Italie, depuis la renaissance des beaux-arts, jusques vers la fin du XVIIIe siècle*, Luigi Lanzi](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k202235g/f221.image.r=)